# How to use self in @dispatch

Tags: python

I use python and i need redefine my method of class with another args. I use dispatch, but i don't now how to put in decorator this class

```py
from multipledispatch import dispatch


class My_Fraction:
    def __init__(self, num: int, den: int):
        if den == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError("Fraction's denominator can't be 0")
        self.num = num
        self.den = den

    def simplify(self):
        for _ in range(min(self.num, self.den), 1, -1):
            if self.num % _ == 0 and self.den % _ == 0:
                self.num = self.num // _
                self.den = self.den // _
                self.simplify()

    @dispatch(int)
    def multiply(self, number: int):
        self.num = self.num * number
        self.den = self.den
        self.simplify()

    @dispatch(__class__)
    def multiply(self, fraction: __class__):
        self.num = self.num * fraction.num
        self.den = self.den * fraction.den
        self.simplify()


a = My_Fraction(1, 10)
b = My_Fraction(1, 2)
a.multiply(b)
print(a.num, a.den, sep="\n---\n")
b.multiply(2)
print(b.num, b.den, sep="\n---\n")
```

i want that in second `multiply' i have arg with type` My_Fraction`
but this code don't working because in moment of using decoorator my class is not defined yet. Please say me how to do it?

*I know that classes names should be CamelCase, but this task need it*

I try to put in decorator `self`, `My_Fraction`, `__class__` and i doesn't work. I don't know how to do it